# Symfony parameter in annotation of doctrine entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a Entity using a different database than the one in use by the default connection, so into entity's annotations i have put :

```
        /**
     * MyClassName
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="mytable", schema="`myschema`")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\...\MyClassNameRepository")
     */
    class MyClassName
    {
...
```

It 's work.

But i would like to set schema like this :

```
schema="`%myapp.specificschema%`"
```

I want to do that because i want to set a different name of database in production and environnement, and i want to change this parameter only once in only one file.
But it's seems to be impossible because doctrine cannot access parameters ...

Thanks in advance for any reply !

Comment: Can you show us your configuration file config.yml

Comment: I think you will have to switch from annotations to xml

Comment: I have tested the xml instead of annotation, it's not working better... May be i should use a another entity manager but it's a piece of work ...

Comment: Bof, not working better...

Comment: @Coolhand, as you indicate in your deleted message that my answer work, please accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade from n3k answer to manage AssociationMappings

-- Entity--

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(schema="primary", name="**table_entity_name**", ...)
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Entity
{
       /**
        * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="**path\To\Entity\ManyToMany**" ...)
        * @ORM\JoinTable(
        *      schema="secondary",
        *      name="**table_field_name**",
        *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_join_***", referencedColumnName="id")},
        *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_inverse_***", referencedColumnName="id")}
        * )
        */
    private $fieldManyToMany ;
}
```

-- SchemaDoctrineSubscriber --

!! getEnvSchemaName() is there to quickly manage schema names

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Doctrine ;


use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber ;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs ;





/**
 * Permet de modifier les noms des tables (schemas) depuis les paramètres
 */
class SchemaDoctrineSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * Nom des schemas
     *
     * string
     */
    private $schema_primary ;
    private $schema_secondary ;





    /**
     *
     * @param string $schema_primary
     * @param string $schema_secondary
     */
    public function __construct($schema_primary, $schema_secondary)
    {
        $this->schema_primary   = $schema_primary ;
        $this->schema_secondary = $schema_secondary ;
    }



    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return ['loadClassMetadata'] ;
    }



    /**
     * @param LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata() ;

        // Modifie les schemas des AssociationMappings de l'entité
        foreach ($classMetadata->getAssociationMappings() as $key => $associationMapping)
            if (isset($associationMapping['joinTable']))
            {
                $associationMapping['joinTable']['schema'] = $this->getEnvSchemaName($classMetadata->getSchemaName()) ;

                $classMetadata->setAssociationOverride($key, $associationMapping) ;
            }

        // Modifie le schema  de l'entité
        $classMetadata->table['schema'] = $this->getEnvSchemaName($classMetadata->getSchemaName()) ;
    }



    /**
     * Retourne le nom du schema de l'environnement
     *
     * @param string $classMetadataSchemaName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getEnvSchemaName($classMetadataSchemaName)
    {
        switch ($classMetadataSchemaName)
        {
            case 'primary':
                return $this->schema_primary ;

            case 'secondary':
                return $this->schema_secondary ;
        }
    }
}
```

Services.yml

```
# Permet de modifier les noms des tables (schemas) depuis les paramètres
doctrine.schema_name.subscriber:
    class: AppBundle\Doctrine\SchemaDoctrineSubscriber
    arguments: ["%databases.primary.schema.name%", "%databases.secondary.schema.name%"]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: **main_connection** }
```

Parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    databases.primary.schema.name:      **primary_schema_name**
    databases.secondary.schema.name:      **secondary_schema_name**
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the schema with the Doctrine loadMetadata Event.
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#load-classmetadata-event

For example, with the subscriber pattern, we should have something like this :

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    schema_name: "my_schema_name"
```

**services.yml**

```
doctrine.schema_name.subscriber:
    class: App\Doctrine\SchemaDoctrineSubscriber
    arguments: ["%schema_name%"]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

**And the corresponding class  :**

```
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;

class SchemaDoctrineSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    /** @var string */
    private $schemaName;

    /**
     * SchemaDoctrineSubscriber constructor.
     * @param string $schemaName
     */
    public function __construct(string $schemaName)
    {
        $this->schemaName = $schemaName;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'loadClassMetadata',
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();
        if ($classMetadata->getTableName() === 'mytable') {
            $classMetadata->table['schema'] = $this->schemaName;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can juste leave the `schema` property empty in the annotation, the event will set the good value on it.

Comment: for me, after following this code. the schema still not changed. But after set it manual via annotations, changing schema success.. 

After checking inside `$classMetadata` , schema is changed but it wont work on my symfony.